# Shinken - Anyone using it?

Tags: monitoring, python, nagios

I've recently discovered [Shinken](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/), which is a new implementation of Nagios using python. Shinken "divides" Nagios in 5 different types of daemons, each one performing separated tasks. I haven't tried it yet but for what I've seen the whole architecture idea seems great to me (it works the Unix way: one process, one task), but the project seems a little "green" yet.

So, has anyone tried Shinken? What's your opinion?

Comment: Guess I'll have to make my own tests :)

Comment: Add me to the tester list.

Comment: interesting... I will try it.

Comment: Very nice. I will definitely give it a try and report back. I see this at the bottom though:
> It’s not ready for production environments, but it’s good enough for QA!

Comment: They weren't kidding when they said not ready for production. Documentation is quite incomplete (many sections still refer to Nagios). This definitely sounds promising though. Fast, reliable, redundant, what else could one ask for?

Comment: I think this is a discussion that fits for a forum or something, but it's not a solvable question for which this site is intended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've been playing with Shinken for a few days now. Seems to work as advertised with very low resource utilization, which is always a plus. The software is definitely not ready for production though and is very rough around the edges. This just replaces the core Nagios engine, as you still need an external web interface to interact with it (of which there are plenty of alternatives). Documentation really needs to be updated and spell checked :D

This is a very promising project though, one that I will keep a close eye on.

Answer (score 6):

Shinken is now used in small and large enterprise environments.

In March 2012, version 1.x was released and is considered stable with all features working as advertised.

The main documentation does have many references to Nagios, but most of the configuration ***-is-*** the same as Nagios. Shinken specific documentations has been improved and reorganized quite a bit. (some spell checking and style passes have been done, but it's a wiki so any spell checking is welcome. ;-))

Shinken is pure open-source with a high development velocity and the devs are industry pros, so it is a project to try and see if there is a fit with your requirements.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using it quite yet, but the idea is fascinating. I'll be working with the project owner to update documentation, as the project has developed quickly.

Has anyone used it since May? I've only run the installation; I haven't set up monitoring yet.